# Creating a Adjustment before Processing a (pick,pack,ship) scan

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an Adjustment to my stock as I am scanning the item.

The code works and the adjustment is released as expected. The problem is the data is not submitted to SQL before the base method is invoked. Is there a way to force the data to be pushed to SQL before the base method is called?

I have tried adding a PXTransactionScope but after the ts.complete the data on SQL has not been updated

```
 [PXOverride]
 public virtual void ProcessLotSerialBarcode(string barcode, ProcessLotSerialBarcodeDelegate baseMethod)
    {

                string LotnumberWithOutPrf =// code to extract Lotnumber from QR code

                //check if lot has stock
                INItemLotSerial iNItemLotSerial = PXSelect<
                    INItemLotSerial,
                    Where<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, Equal<Required<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr>>,
                    And<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID>>>>>
                    .Select(Base, Lotnumber, Base.HeaderView.Current.InventoryID);

                //if there is no stock do adjustment 
                if (iNItemLotSerial.QtyHardAvail == 0)
                {
                    using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                    {
                        INAdjustmentEntry iNAdjustmentEntryEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INAdjustmentEntry>();
                        INRegister iNRegister = new INRegister();

                        iNRegister.ExtRefNbr = "N/A";
                        iNRegister.TranDesc = "Adjustment for Shipment: " + Base.HeaderView.Current.RefNbr;
                        iNRegister.Hold = false;
                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Insert(iNRegister);

                        INTran iNTran = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.transactions.Insert();

                        iNTran.InventoryID = Base.HeaderView.Current.InventoryID;
                        iNTran.SiteID = 9;
                        iNTran.LocationID = 77;
                        iNTran.Qty = 1;
                        iNTran.UOM = Base.HeaderView.Current.UOM;
                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.transactions.Update(iNTran);
                        iNTran.LotSerialNbr = LotnumberWithOutPrf;

                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.transactions.Update(iNTran);

                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.Save.PressButton();
                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.release.Press();
                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.Save.PressButton();
                        iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.Cancel.PressButton(); 
                        ts.Complete(Base);
                    }
                }

                baseMethod?.Invoke(LotnumberWithOutPrf);
    }
```

Comment: The method you are overriding is already within a transaction scope so all data writ within any custom method therein will also be committed or roll-backed in sync with the calling method. A solution is do-able but is not methodology I would utilize if at all possible due to the number of problems it will introduce if any aspect overlooked. I can post in a few days.

Could you expand on why you desire these changes to be persisted pre-base method invocation? I do not have in depth familiarity with the process.

Comment: The adjustment is done because the item is not in the lot that was just scanned. We use one lot number for one item thus if the lot is empty on the system there was a mistake prior. The Base method then fails as the need adjustment has not been saved/released.

Comment: hi Joshua, have you had a second to look at this again? What was your plan to do the "sub transaction" if I can call it that, i can also look into it